# Apache TomEE Memory Leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, apache-tomee

we have started using tomEE 1.7. we are facing memory leak issue. After 2 weeks we are getting outofmemoryerror.

we analyzed the heapdump and found one concurrentHashMap(creatonalContexts) is holding all objects in **org.apache.openejb.core.WebContext creatonalContexts**

1. Why it is holding all obecjts ?
2. Why it is not getting release from that Map ?
3. What actually it is holding ?
4. IS there any memory optimization in tomEE ?
5. is there any fix in tomEE for memory leak ?

we are using EJB3 and Struts 2.

Regards,
Gnana

Comment: We are using EJB3 and Vaadin and never reached that issue

Comment: Have you tried snapshot of TomEE 2/1.7.2? Maybe its already fixed there.

Comment: I noticed all objects coming under org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.IfTag. any one knows why this IfTag hold all my report object

Comment: Try to move commonly used jars to a common location in TomEE sever directory

Comment: Sasi ,Can u give more details on that

Comment: FibreFoX, can u give exact detils on this

Answer (score 1):

TomEE server BodyContentImpl, member variable 'cb' char[] hold maximum memory. it is defect and solvtion is add below mentioned property in Catalino propery.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37793

**-Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true**